# HTTP 500.19 – configuration data is invalid

Tags: c#, rest, web-services, .net-core

I created web service application on .net Core 2.2, it works fine on VS IIS Express, but windows server 2012 IIS 8 it throwing error :

The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid

I checked config file which was generated in published version and it was :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\WebServices.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 2ffcb152-3fb6-43b8-aa45-784eed3432bf-->
```

I checked it in online validator and it was ok, so i have no clue.

Comment: Did you install the hosting bundle and restart IIS?

Comment: i will try , thanks